# Uncaught (in promise) Error: "QrScanner" plugin is not implemented on android (capacitor-community / barcode-scanner)

Tags: android, quasar-framework, iso, capacitor-plugin

I am working on a Quasar App Project with Capacitor. I need a QR Reader For scan QR in Android and IOS, In my web view the plugin is working either my Andorid and iso device.at Emulator There is an eror messeg [ Uncaught (in promise) Error: "QrScanner" plugin is not implemented on android ]. I dont know why i am facing this eror . Is there anyone who face and solve this proble..

My Full project has been stuck for this qr scanner !

I am trying a lot but can't solve the issue , If anyone know beeter soluition for using another plugin or else please tell me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.